# Angular 4 - TypeError: this.changeHook is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

[![image or error
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzykY.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzykY.png)Angular 4 application whenever I type in input text boxes 
`TypeError: this.changeHook is not a function` - message shows up in console. I am not able to figure out what is this error. Any Ideas.

****UPDATE****
It comes only for second input text box not for the second input textbox. 
As soon as I type in second input box, the number of charcters typed in, that many error with same message shows up in console.

HTML

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let reasoncode of displayReasonCodes$ | async;let i = index">
 <tr class= "row-break">

 <checkbox type="checkbox"  name="sizecb[]" value="{{reasoncode.id}}"  [(ngModel)]="reasoncode.state">
      </checkbox>


       <td>  
          <form>
           <form-group>

  <textbox [readOnly]="isEditable" ngModel="{{reasoncode.ReasonCode}}"  name="textbox" ></textbox>
                                            </form-group>

                                    </form>

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                                     <form>
                                                            <form-group>

                                                              <textbox ngModel="{{reasoncode.Description}}" name="textbox1" ></textbox>
                                                            </form-group>

                                                    </form>

                            </td>
```

COMPONENT -

```
       @Component({
    selector: 'app-reason-codes',
    templateUrl: './reason-codes.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./reason-codes.component.scss'],
    providers: [ ReasonCodesActions],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,

  })


  export class ReasonCodesComponent implements OnInit {
    poolModel: ReasonCodeFormUIModel;



    IReasonCodes: IReasonCodes[]=[]; 


    i:any;
    @select(store.isReasonCodeLoading) isLoading$: Observable<boolean>;
    @select(store.displayReasonCodes) displayReasonCodes$:Observable<IReasonCodes>;
    @select(store.isDisplayMessage) displayMessage$: Observable<boolean>;
    @select(store.componentType) componentType$: Observable<number>;


    Active:any;




    addCodes:boolean;
    state:any;
     $event:any;
    displayReasonCodes:any;



    headers = [
        { label: 'REASON CODES ', sort: false },
        { label: 'DESCRIPTION', sort: false },
        { label: 'STATUS', sort :false}
      ];


      constructor(private reasonCodesActions : ReasonCodesActions,
        private uiActions:UIActions) {
      }

    ngOnInit (){



       this.displayReasonCodes$.subscribe(data=>this.result=data); 



     this.reasonCodesActions.getReasonCodes();

    }






      Addrow(){ console.log("add");
      this.isEditable=false;
        this.reasonCodesActions.Addrow();
      }


      refresh(){
        location.reload();
      }
```

Comment: Could you please show the code that led to the error?

Comment: Please share your code with the html for the input and the component that contains it.

Comment: @edkeveked - updated

Comment: @Narm - updated

Comment: @user8819437 Please, consider to do the formatting to allow easy reading :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue - 
I was not using any input property on the input box in my template. so it was not able to recognize the input. As soon as i added the input property, the error went away from console.